# What all does getPersistenceManager().refresh(entity) load?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I came across a part of code in my project where `getPersistenceManager().refresh(entity);` is used. When I checked the Hibernate queries that get fired. There are few other queries which get fired and are child elements of the entity to be refreshed.

Why are those queries fired? Why not queries for all child entities fired?

EDIT:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entity", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_TABLE", nullable = false)
private List<Employee> employee; // This is an example. Actual code resembles this example.
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have failed to post any code it is difficult to say, however the most likely explanation is that the relevant cascade options are not defined on the association.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html#REFRESH

```
@Entity
public class Parent{

    // on of the following would have to be defined
    //@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    public Set<Child> children;

}
```